# Android RecyclerView doesn't recycle items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have A `recyclerView` that have multiple `recyclerView` with a dynamic inflation, the response I

am getting from the server is a list that contains objects each one contains a list and attributes for the

`recyclerView` type (`Vertical` or `Horizontal`) LinearLayout.

everything works fine except that when the orienatation is Vertical the adapter wait to load all Views at once (stop recycling).

I have searched a lot to find a solution but nothing.

#### the Main `RecyclerView` inside `HomeFragment`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.gt.gcook.ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/home_single_item" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### home_single_item layout (contains of 2 `TextView` and `RecyclerView`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seeAllTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:text="See all"
        android:textColor="@color/color_yellow"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Catigories"
        android:textColor="#707070"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        app:reverseLayout="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTV" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### `onBindViewHolder` of Home `RecyclerView` .

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    when (position) {
        0 -> {
            holder.itemView.titleTV.text = "Categories"
            val mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(holder.itemView.context)
            mLayoutManager.orientation = RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL
            holder.itemView.recyclerView.layoutManager = mLayoutManager
            holder.itemView.recyclerView.adapter = HomeCategoryAdapter()


        }
        1 -> { //here is the problem when Orintation is vertical.
            holder.itemView.titleTV.text = "Most rated recipes"
            val mLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(holder.itemView.context, 2)
            mLayoutManager.orientation = RecyclerView.VERTICAL
            holder.itemView.recyclerView.layoutManager = mLayoutManager
            holder.itemView.recyclerView.adapter = MostRatedRecipeAdapter(clickListener)


        }
        else -> {
            holder.itemView.titleTV.text = "Favourite"
            val mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(holder.itemView.context)
            mLayoutManager.orientation = RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL
            holder.itemView.recyclerView.layoutManager = mLayoutManager
            holder.itemView.recyclerView.adapter = HomeCategoryAdapter()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a complicated issue, but the long story short is that RecyclerViews inside other scrolling containers (like a RecyclerView...) causes the whole thing to stop recycling. I have observed this when you put a recyclerView inside a NestedScrollView or similar. It likely has to do with the "wrap_content" attributes causing the RV to inflate all views to determine what the space needed/available is, or perhaps the container unable to correctly size itself unless the RV reports "the total" space it needs... quite lame if you ask me :/

Comment: Lame? it is exactly what `wrap_content` means **and adding `wrap_content` to RV doesn't make sens as you can only scroll something bigger in smaller container**  wrap_content makes container and content even... also recycling works when inner RV has defined height ...

Comment: @Selvin so do you have a solution or work around for that issue?

Comment: There is no solution. You cannot get view recycling on a recyclerview which is nested in another recyclerview. There are mutlipe SO posts verifying this. Either you live with it, or restructure your code to provide one flat list of items to one recyclerview.

Comment: There is so much room for optimization actually...

Comment: @Rinat what do you mean?

Comment: @MohamedAbdelraZek you can use pagination in the second Recyclerview it may help to solve the issue a bit.

Comment: I added "answer"  below, since it wouldn't fit in a comment. Sorry for late response :)

Comment: In rep history it's shown that you unaccepted the answer (or tried). I wonder if there is something wrong with the answer or was it just a missclick?

Comment: Sorry, just a missclick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your **inner** `RV`'s  height is set to `wrap_content` there is no way to enable recycling for that case. When its horizontal, recycling  is working because it's `width` is `match_parent` and screen width is fixed. Recycling works only when there is defined height!

However, as i said there is room for optimization:

Right now, you are creating adapter for **inner** `RV` inside parent RV's `onBindViewHolder()` method, thus forcing inner `RV` to inflate `ViewHolders` every time **parent** `RV` decides to reuse it's previous `ViewHolders` via rebinding new values.

You can create adapters for **inner** `RV` inside `onCreateVoewHolder()` of **parent** `RV` and submit new list to **inner**  adapter ( subsequently calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` ) inside `OnBindViewHolder()`.

The above approach should certainly improve performance, at least on subsequent scrolling: recycling will work on **parent** `RV` scroll, meaning  **inner** `RV` will retain its `ViewHolders` and reuse them to some degree.

Unfortunately, i don't have time to post snippet precisely for your scenario but you can have a look at my another answer:
[Show values of same key in one TextView in Recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63045236/show-values-of-same-key-in-one-textview-in-recyclerview/63118092#63118092)